# Can electrons be accelerated by means of an inhomogeneous magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields

A copper wire contains a sea of free electrons. Can these electrons be accelerated by means of a magnetic field gradient, thus generating voltage in the wire?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the magnetic field changes over time. This is how an [electric generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_generator) works.

Comment: I read somewhere that a team of Japanese scientists managed to accelerate neutrons by means of an inhomogeneous magnetic field, as the neutron has a magnetic moment. So I was wondering if the same thing can be achieved with electrons instead of neutrons and ion lattice (copper wire) instead of vacuum for medium in which particles move.

Comment: @Eduard Can you still find the source that describes that neutrons were accelerated in the inhomogeneous magnetic field?

Comment: This is the source
https://www.rri.kyoto-u.ac.jp/news-en/4964